# How to delete a .p12 file from Login.keychain that i imported from cli?

Tags: console, keychain, p12

I imported a .p12 file to Login.keychain with cli:

> $ security import /Users/xxx/Desktop/Certificates.p12 -k Login.keychain -P 1234 -A

#### But how to delete this file from Login.keychain with cli?

#### System: MacOS

Answer (score 0):

Probably you can use below command

```
ls -l ~/Library/Keychains/
rm -rf ~/Library/Keychains/Login.keychain
```

Comment: This will delete all item in Login.keychain?

Comment: I think you need to run below command to delete the specific item in keychains. Give a try please . I tried on my machine and I am able to get the hash for it. security find-certificate -c "certificatename" -a -Z | \
  sudo awk '/SHA-1/{system("security delete-certificate -Z "$NF)}'